# Java TreeMap Comparator

Tags: java, comparator, treemap, sortedmap

I need a comparator for a TreeMap. Should I write this anonymously in the constructor for my TreeMap? How else could I write my comparator. Currently, Java does not like my code (can I do this anonymously?):

```
SortedMap<String, Double> myMap = 
    new TreeMap<String, Double>(new Comparator<Entry<String, Double>>()
    {
        public int compare(Entry<String, Double> o1, Entry<String, Double> o2)
        {
            return o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue());
        } 
    });
```

1. Can I do the above anonymously?
2. How else could I do this?
3. I want to sort myMap by the Value not the Key

Comment: The TreeMap comparator signature is on the key only. For example:  
```
new Comparator<String>() {
  @Override
  public int compare(String a, String b) { return 0; }
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can not sort [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) on values.

> A Red-Black tree based NavigableMap implementation. The map is sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys, or by a Comparator provided at map creation time, depending on which constructor is used
>   You will need to provide `comparator` for `Comparator<? super K>` so your comparator should compare on keys.

To provide sort on values you will need [SortedSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html). Use

```
SortedSet<Map.Entry<String, Double>> sortedset = new TreeSet<Map.Entry<String, Double>>(
            new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Double>>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Double> e1,
                        Map.Entry<String, Double> e2) {
                    return e1.getValue().compareTo(e2.getValue());
                }
            });

  sortedset.addAll(myMap.entrySet());
```

To give you an example

```
    SortedMap<String, Double> myMap = new TreeMap<String, Double>();
    myMap.put("a", 10.0);
    myMap.put("b", 9.0);
    myMap.put("c", 11.0);
    myMap.put("d", 2.0);
    sortedset.addAll(myMap.entrySet());
    System.out.println(sortedset);
```

Output:

```
  [d=2.0, b=9.0, a=10.0, c=11.0]
```

Comment: How do I add an element one at a time to myMap? myMap.add(Map.Entry<String, Double> new Map.Entry<String, Double>(vStr, cur));

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus  No. you use put method only Check the example that is added. You put values to Map once your are done use SortedSet to sort values.

Comment: This works but it removes duplicate values. But i want to keep duplicate values in the list. Can anyone help me?

Comment: ..or "even you take elements and order them, when you put them back into a TreeMap, the order is still decided by the **key** comparator/natural order". Instead, you can insert the ordered entries into a `LinkedHashmap` to at least return an ordered map view of elements.

Comment: @PriyankaAlachiya Use an ArrayList instead of a set. Add the elements of the map to the list and pass in the comparator in Collections.sort(). Worked for me. Also I used technique when solving "Top K Frequent Elements" on leetcode

Answer (score 18):

The comparator should be only for the key, not for the whole entry. It sorts the entries based on the keys.

You should change it to something as follows

```
SortedMap<String, Double> myMap = 
    new TreeMap<String, Double>(new Comparator<String>()
    {
        public int compare(String o1, String o2)
        {
            return o1.compareTo(o2);
        } 
});
```

**Update**

You can do something as follows (create a list of entries in the map and sort the list base on value, but note this not going to sort the map itself) -

```
List<Map.Entry<String, Double>> entryList = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<String, Double>>(myMap.entrySet());
    Collections.sort(entryList, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Double>>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Entry<String, Double> o1, Entry<String, Double> o2) {
            return o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue());
        }
    });
```

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus: You cannot sort the map itself based on values. But you can get list of entries and sort it. But then it might not make sense to have a TreeMap, unless you switch the key and value.

Answer (score 0):

you can swipe the key and the value. For example

```
        String[] k = {"Elena", "Thomas", "Hamilton", "Suzie", "Phil"};
        int[] v = {341, 273, 278, 329, 445};
        TreeMap<Integer,String>a=new TreeMap();
        for (int i = 0; i < k.length; i++) 
           a.put(v[i],k[i]);            
        System.out.println(a.firstEntry().getValue()+"\t"+a.firstEntry().getKey());
        a.remove(a.firstEntry().getKey());
        System.out.println(a.firstEntry().getValue()+"\t"+a.firstEntry().getKey());
```

Comment: This is trying to solve the last question, but not the first two.