# Java data structures: IndexedSet or HashList

Tags: java, data-structures, guava

Is there a Java data structure that satisfies the following requirements?

1. Indexed access. (i.e., i should be able to retrieve objects with `get(i)`)
2. Constant time `get()` & `contains()` methods
3. Should enforce ordering (enforced by `Comparator`)
4. Should be mutable

I could not find any in `Oracle's JDK` or `Guava` that gives the above listed features out of the box

`List` provides indexed access & some kind of ordering but not constant-time `contains()`. `SortedSet` and `SortedMap` provide constant-time `contains()` and sorting but not indexed access!!

Am I missing something or is there any data structure out there that could be manipulated to provide the features listed above?

**My current solution:**

A combination of `HashMap` & `ArrayList` => I use `ArrayList` to store the sorted keys which provides indexed access and use `HashMap` for constant-time `contains()` method. I just wanna make sure that I am not trying to re-invent something that has already been done

**Why I need this:**

Let's call this data structure `SortedDataStore`
I am developing an Android app & most of the UI in that is a list of items and these items are pulled off the local db. (the local db gets its data from a remote server). The UI is populated using `RecyclerView` and I need constant-time indexed access to get the object from my `SortedDataStore` and populate the views. Since the order of items is decided based on their attributes, there is a need for sorting. Also the data gets updated a lot (items get modified, deleted and new items get added). When the new data comes in, I check against my `SortedDataStore` if it should be deleted, or added or modified (and moved to another index) for which I need constant-time `contains()` & mutability.

Comment: Any reason an [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) does not work?

Comment: You don't place any time requirements on insertion. What about wrapping an `ArrayList`, then calling `Collections.sort` after every insertion?

Comment: Use a combination of hashmap and List, though it is memory inefficient but will solve the purpose. use index as key map to get constant access time.

Comment: @appak, @GriffeyDog - I forgot to put in conditions about `contains()`. Please have  a look at the edited question

Comment: @Satty - That is exactly what I am using right now. I just wanted to make sure that I am not reinventing the wheel

Comment: This feels like premature optimization to me, especially since on a bellow answer you commented saying you will only have a few hundred to a few thousand elements. A sorted ArrayList and Collections.binarySearch() will work very well. If you are having performance problems in the view I would guess it is from something else.

Comment: @Appak - Indeed it is a case of premature optimization it seems!! I will move to ArrayList

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Based on what you've described as your expected data size, `ArrayList` seems like it would actually be just fine in practice -- your data isn't big enough for the linear-time factor to matter that much.
- Otherwise, what you're doing is the right solution; there's no provided mutable data structure that does all that at once.
- If you can avoid mutation, Guava's `ImmutableSet` satisfies the rest of your demands.   You can use `ImmutableSet.asList().get(index)` to get out elements by index in O(1) time, and otherwise it supports O(1) contains and insertion order.

Comment: What kind of mutation?  There's certainly no way to have `remove` be O(1) and support all your other constraints.

Comment: addition and removal processes need not be O(1). It is just the retrieval and contains operations that have got to be O(1).

Comment: Then what you're doing now is probably the right approach; there isn't any built-in way otherwise.

Comment: (Though can you go into more detail about what exactly you need this structure?  Are you sure you can't e.g. just populate it once and then leave it?)

Comment: I have added the reasons for why i need such a data structure. Please have a look at the edit

Comment: How big do you expect this data structure to get?  How many elements?

Comment: It ranges any where from a few hundred to few thousand elements

Comment: I'd actually suspect you don't need constant time and that an `ArrayList` would suffice, but otherwise you've already got the right solution.

Comment: (For a data structure that small, linear time isn't actually that big a price to pay.)

Comment: Can you please edit your answer to reflect the comments? I would be happy to mark you answer as accepted

Answer (score 2):

An `ArrayList` satisfies the three requirements:

- Indexed access, using `get(int i)`
- Constant time access, using `get(int i)`
- Order by insertion, using `add(Object o)`

Comment: I forgot to put in conditions about `contains()`. Please have  a look at the edited question

Answer (score 2):

[Java's LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) satisfies your requirements if you use an index as your key.

1. Indexed access: use `get(i)`
2. Constant time get() & contains() methods: use `get(i)` and `containsKey()`
3. Should enforce ordering (enforced by Comparator): see note
4. Should be mutable: yes

Note

If you want a custom comparator, extend the `Comparable` interface and `@Override` the `compareTo()` method on the class of the child object.

[comparator for LinkedHashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16294134/comparator-for-linkedhashmap)