# What is comparable type casting & Map.Entry?

Tags: java, interface, compare, comparator, compareto

I am new in Java.
I am implementing Comparator interface & i am having a compareTo function below:-

```
public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
    Map.Entry e1 = (Map.Entry) o1;
    Map.Entry e2 = (Map.Entry) o2;
    return ((Comparable) e1.getValue()).compareTo(e2.getValue());
}
```

I am not be able to understand what does this line means

```
Map.Entry e1 = (Map.Entry) o1;
```

What is the use of two `Map.Entry` ??

Why `Comparable` in type casting ??

Someone please give me a reference so that i can figure it out.
Thanks.

Edited:-
Here is my whole class,i am having a HashMap
I want to sort by values using Generic class,hence writing this class

```
package via;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class SortMap<K, V> {
    public Map<K, V> getSortedMap(Map<K, V> mapToSort) {
        List<Map.Entry> list = new ArrayList<Map.Entry>(mapToSort.entrySet());
        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator() {

            @Override
            public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
                Map.Entry e1 = (Map.Entry) o1;
                Map.Entry e2 = (Map.Entry) o2;
                return ((Comparable) e2.getValue()).compareTo(e1.getValue());
            }

        });
        Map sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap();
        for(Iterator i=list.iterator();i.hasNext();)
        {
            Map.Entry entry=(Map.Entry)i.next();
            sortedMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
        System.out.println(list);
        return sortedMap;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the complete class? And you should implement the parameterized `Comparator` rather than the raw type.

Comment: It looks like you're implementing the *raw* `Comparator` interface - any reason you're not implementing it as `Comparator<Map.Entry<String, String>>` or whatever?

Comment: As i mentioned earlier,i am new bee to java so don'w know what is happening here.
I am having only little idea about it.

Comment: If you are new to Java, then try some simple comparator/comparable example. there are loads of them on Google.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I want to compare the Map.Entry instances.

Comment: Why don't you use a TreeMap instead of writing this class? Try this: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_treemap_class.htm

Comment: @user2424380 i want sorting them by values not by keys.

Comment: @vicky : sorry, didn't notice. And what about this (see the accepted answer here) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12947088/java-treemap-comparator

Answer (score 2):

I am considering here, both K,V are String values. If you have some other values then first your classes for K,V should follow `equals()` and `hashcode()` rules.
Comparable is not required if you follow the following program.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class SortMap {
    public Map<String, String> getSortedMap(Map<String, String> mapToSort) {
        Set<Map.Entry<String,String>> mapEntry = mapToSort.entrySet();

        List<Map.Entry<String,String>> listMap= new ArrayList<Map.Entry<String,String>>();
        listMap.addAll(mapEntry);
        Collections.sort(listMap, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String,String>>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(Map.Entry<String,String> o1, Map.Entry<String,String> o2) {
                return  o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue());
            }

        });
        Map<String,String> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
        for(Map.Entry<String,String> mapE:listMap)
        {
            sortedMap.put(mapE.getKey(), mapE.getValue());
        }
        System.out.println(sortedMap);
        return sortedMap;
    }

}
```

**Map.Entry** is nothing but **Entry** class written inside **HashMap** class which implements **Entry** interface which is written inside **Map** interface. so there are rules to use inner class references.

```
static class Entry<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K,V> {
        final K key;
        V value;
        Entry<K,V> next;
        final int hash;

        /**
         * Creates new entry.
         */
        Entry(int h, K k, V v, Entry<K,V> n) {
            value = v;
            next = n;
            key = k;
            hash = h;
        }
}
```

Comment: Same way i have approached earlier.
It is not giving compareTo function to compare the objects values.

Comment: Because that reference is of type `Object` and it doesn't have `compareTo` method.